# variable from php function in sqlite reference

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to reference a variable in another reference in sqlite. Right now I have this, and it just errors

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range

The problem is on the line `(filmnummer, acteurnummer) VALUES (film.?.filmnummer,?);"` And I know that, is wrong, but I don't know what to replace it with so it works.

```
public function add_film($title, $genre, $actor, $director, $agecategory, $warning){
        $query = $this->db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO film
            (title, agecategorynumber) VALUES (?,?);
            INSERT INTO filmactor
            (filmnummer, actornumber) VALUES (film.?.filmnumber,?);"
        );

        $query->bindValue(1, $title);
        $query->bindValue(2, $agecategory);
        $query->bindValue(3, $title);
        $query->bindValue(4, $actor);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could concat the value in the binding and not in the query eg:

```
public function add_film($title, $genre, $actor, $director, $agecategory, $warning){
        $query = $this->db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO film
            (title, agecategorynumber) VALUES (:a,:b);
            INSERT INTO filmactor
            (filmnummer, actornumber) VALUES (:c,:d);"
        );

        $query->bindValue(':a', $title);
        $query->bindValue(':b', $agecategory);
        $query->bindValue(':c', 'film'. $title . 'filmnumber');
        $query->bindValue(':d', $actor);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but sadly it still gave the same error as before